# Group Function is not applying on Character Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in Oracle table like this format

```
Gname, PBOOK, CNIC,  LPNAME, ACRE 
Bilal  1234   33202  A            
       1234          A       2    
       1234          A       2    
Adeel  5678   35230  B            
       5678          B       3    
       5678          B       5
```

I want to sum up the acre filed and data should look like this

```
   Gname, PBOOK, CNIC,  LPNAME, SUM(ACRE) 
    Bilal  1234   33202  A       4    
    Adeel  5678   35230  B       8
```

Plz give any Idea to make such kind of sql statement in oracle so my desired output should be generated

Comment: Is there a reason for this table design?  You'd probably save yourself a lot of hassle in the future by normalising the table.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why does a simple `sum(acre)` not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you exactly, but you can try:

```
  SELECT max(Gname), PBOOK, max(CNIC),  LPNAME, SUM(ACRE)
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY PBOOK, LPNAME
```